How to restore Xubuntu loading circle plymouth theme from 23.10 in 24.04?
Is the loading circle animation on startup and shutdown changed? Back on 23.10, it used to be completely round. Now (24.04) it's wiggly like jelly.

The changelog is https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/x/xubuntu-artwork/xubuntu-artwork_24.04.1/changelog ; but I'm not aware of what you consider has changed sorry (I've not noticed anything)

You can download the older plymouth theme and set it as default
